# Grid appears to be partially freezing

Tags: ag-grid

Using the release 16.0.0 of the enterprise ag-grid.

When I first start the website, I am able to load the grid and the row click and double click events fire.

When i reload (the grid with new data, the grid does not respond to the click or double click event  BUT   i am able to set focus to the grid, and move around the grid using the arrow keys.

Here is my gridOptions

```
var gridOptions = {
columnDefs: columnDefs,
enableColResize: true,
enableSorting: true,
rowSelection: 'single',
getMainMenuItems: getMainMenuItems,
getContextMenuItems: getContextMenuItems,
allowContextMenuWithControlKey: true,
popupParent: document.querySelector('body'),
onGridReady: function (params) {
},
onRowDoubleClicked: function (params) {
popupCard(params.node.data.cardID);
},
onRowClicked: function (params) {
  popupCard(params.node.data.cardID);
  }
};
```

As mentioned, I am able to navigate after the data reload using the arrow keys, but the click and double click do not seem to fire.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you have defined the functions inside class then you might need to use

```
onRowClicked: function (params) {
    this.popupCard(params.node.data.cardID);
}
```